# cloudera director client installation

Tags: hadoop, cloudera, cloudera-director, apache-spot

I am trying to install apache-spot and Cloudera on AWS following these tutorials:

http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2018/02/apache-spot-incubating-and-cloudera-on-aws-in-60-minutes/

https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/director/latest/topics/director_get_started_aws_install_dir_server.html#concept_xnb_cwh_jx

But when I run:

```
sudo apt-get install cloudera-director-client
```

The Ubuntu terminal gives me:

```
E: unable to locate package cloudera-director-client
```

I already ran this code to fix:

```
$ wget http://archive.cloudera.com/director/ubuntu/precise/amd64/director/cloudera-director.list
$ wget http://archive.cloudera.com/director/ubuntu/precise/amd64/director/archive.key
$ sudo apt-key add archive.key
$ sudo mv cloudera-director.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d
$ sudo apt-get update
```

Anyone able to help me? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The cloudera-director.list file that you have installed is likely old. The one in the URL you have listed is for Ubuntu 12.04 (Precise Pangolin). Make sure that you pick the release that matches your OS version.

Cloudera Altus Director 2.x is available for Ubuntu 14.04 (Trusty Tahr) at http://archive.cloudera.com/director/ubuntu/trusty/amd64/director/

Cloudera Altus Director 6.0.0 is available for Ubuntu 16.04 and 14.04 at http://archive.cloudera.com/director6/6.0.0/ubuntu1604/ or http://archive.cloudera.com/director6/6.0.0/ubuntu1404/

Please try installing again with a new cloudera-director.list and archive.key